# How do I organize a vim plugin with unique syntax elements?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I've written a (basic) vim plugin for myself, and I'm having a difficult time organizing it. Right now, it lives in two files: one in `syntax/` and one in `ftplugin/` (both of which are in `bundle/<plugin name>`. I would like the plugin to be active for various file types, **including those with existing syntax files**.

So far, doing something like `:set ft=<existing filetype>.<new filetype>` in each file works, but I can't figure out how to (consistently) do this from, say, my .vimrc.

So, two questions:

1. Do I have the right organizational approach? Is there an easier way to (say) combine the syntax and plugin files?
2. If so, what's the "right" way to append my custom `filetype`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though you didn't include a lot of details, you're right in that `syntax/` contains syntax definitions (i.e. mostly `:syntax` commands) and `ftplugin/` is for filetype-specific settings (i.e. mostly `:setlocal`, `:map <buffer>`, etc.).

> I would like the plugin to be active for various file types, including those with existing syntax files.

The correct approach depends a lot on the relationship between the original syntax and yours. It's hard to extend arbitrary syntaxes, because you have to consider overlaps and use the appropriate `containedin=...` specifiers in your syntax extension.

The *compound filetype* `:setl filetype=c.doxygen` works well when auto-detecting or manually setting it. If you don't want the extension to be so visible (and some plugins don't handle compound filetypes well), you can alternatively `:runtime syntax/mine.vim` in all `~/.vim/after/syntax/original.vim` files (and do the same for `ftplugin/`).

Another alternative is hooking into `:autocmd Syntax ...` and `:autocmd FileType ...`; this avoids writing many short stub files that just `:runtime` your syntax / ftplugin additions.

Comment: So, assuming I have the correct organizational approach, I need help setting the compound filetype consistently. I have the line `autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.<orignal> setlocal ft=<original_ft>.<my_ft>` in my .vimrc, which seems to work. Would I need to add a line for every filetype I want my plugin active for?

Comment: With that approach, you're bypassing the original filetype detection (i.e. from `*.<original>` to `<original_ft>`, and would have to duplicate everything. Better hook into the `autocmd FileType` event (which is fired by the original detection), and then conditionally append your filetype (which fires the event again, so check for an existing `<my_ft>`!)

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand what you mean by "hook into the `autocmd FileType` event. Could you be more specific, or provide an example? Thank you.

Comment: That would be `:autocmd FileType <original_ft> setlocal ft=<original_ft.<my_ft>`; see, no file pattern is involved, the default Vim detection rules still do that for you.

Comment: Excellent. It wasn't clear to me from looking at the help files that `FileType` could be used in that way. Thank you for bearing with me.